# C++ linker error when calling template function that is defined in header

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, linker

I'm getting a linking error when calling a template function, but the linker error does not seem to point to the template function. It seems to point to the shared pointer in the function. My class with the template function:

```
class Blackboard {
    public:
    template<class T>
    bool setValue(std::string key, T* value) {
        std::shared_ptr<T> ptr(T);
        boost::any v = ptr;
        auto it = map.insert(std::pair<std::string, boost::any>(key, v));
        return it.second;
    }
}
```

Most similar questions say put all implementation in the header, which I have done. The linking error happens in the class that calls this function. Example class that calls blackboard:

```
class Example {
    void foo(Blackboard* blackboard) {
        int* i = new int;
        *i = 0;
        blackboard->setValue<int>("some key", i);
    }
}
```

The error:

> `Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<int> __cdecl ptr(int)" (?ptr@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@H@std@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl BehaviorTree::Blackboard::setValue<int>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int *)" (??$setValue@H@Blackboard@BehaviorTree@@QEAA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEAH@Z)`

Both the `Blackboard` class and the `Example` class are part of a visual studio static lib project. The linking error occurs when compiling a program using the static library.

I'm having difficulty finding a solution to this problem, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit this into a [mcve]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This is another Most Vexing Parse issue... `ptr` is a function, not a variable.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm -- yes, `ptr` is declared to be the name of a function. I don't see how this is the Most Vexing Parse. Its argument list consists solely of the name of a type. That makes it a function declaration. Nothing subtle here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you wrote

```
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr(T);
```

instead of

```
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr(value);
```

Comment: Wow, this was it. I read your comment like three times before I realized what I did. Thanks!